# Android app has no launch icon

Tags: java, android

been working on my app, I had 3 Icons because I had listed 3 intent filters with the action MAIN.  Tried fixing it, and now I have no icons when the app is installed.  Any idea why I don't have an icon for my app?

MANIFEST

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.myAppName"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<!--
android:targetSdkVersion="17"
 android:targetSdkVersion="17"   
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
-->
<permission android:name="com.myAppName.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.myAppName.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->


<uses-permission android:name="com.myAppName.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.myAppName.activity.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!-- Network State Permissions to detect Internet status -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!-- Permission to vibrate -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.myAppName.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.myAppName.ActivityLogin"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.myAppName.ActivityBonus"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.myAppName.ActivityPersonalRewardsGfits"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.myAppName.ActivityRestaurantDetails"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.myAppName.ActivityRestaurantSearch"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.myAppName.TabManager"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.myAppName.SearchGroupsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.myAppName.TabGroupActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.myAppName.ActivityRegister"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.myAppName.ActivityRestaurantRewards"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.myAppName.ActivityMore"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.myAppName.ActivitySocialConnect"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.myAppName.ActivityAddFriends"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.myAppName.ActivitySharing"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.myAppName.ActivityYourGift"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.myAppName.FriendGroupActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.myAppName.ActivityAddFriendsForSearchRestaurants"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <!-- GCM -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.myAppName" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
    <!-- end of GCM -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"></activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Do you have the icons in the folder drawable?

Comment: Yes, I have an ic_launcher.png in the drawable folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, remove `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` from `FriendGroupActivity`. You do not need it and it is unlikely to be helping.

Second, completely uninstall and reinstall the app, plus restart your device or emulator. Changing the mix of launcher activities is unexpected behavior, and therefore it may take a bit of cajoling to get everything to show up.

Third, if the activity name `SplashScreen` is literal, please get rid of it. Splash screens are an anti-pattern, wasting users' time.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  The `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` that you are referring to was put in so that I can open the app directly to that class from a push notification.  Is that not the proper way to do it? 

I tried reinstalling and rebooting. It did not help.  There is no way to actually open the app unless I have it plugged into my computer and launch it from eclipse.  When I install it via apk, it does not give me the option to open it.

Comment: @tomjung: "Is that not the proper way to do it?" -- no. `LAUNCHER` is for the use by home screen launchers. It has nothing to do with GCM. "There is no way to actually open the app unless I have it plugged into my computer and launch it from eclipse" -- try removing the category as I suggested, then see if your `SplashScreen` activity becomes available in the home screen launcher. It should, as it would appear to have the proper `<intent-filter>`. Also, note that I suggested that you uninstall and reinstall; simply installing over an existing installation may be insufficient.

Comment: @CommonsWare You were correct on the restart.  I uninstalled, restarted then installed. This did not work. Doing it like you said with the uninstall, reinstall then restart did work.  I will remove the splash screen and intent-filter.  Thank you again.